# How to access an NSNumberFormatter in a text field cell?

Tags: interface-builder, xcode4, nsnumberformatter, nstextfieldcell

In XCode 3.2.x's Interface Builder this was simple enough, selecting the text cell displayed a small icon for the formatter that could be selected to configure the formatter in the attributes pane.

Now in XCode 4, the formatter icon is gone! If I drag an instance of NSTextField with an NSTextFormatter from the library OR drop and NSTextFormatter into an existing cell there is no way I can figure out to select the formatter to configure it!

Add to this the fact that Core Data entities UI prototype assistant was removed and I would say IB integration into XC4 is half baked at best!

Any luck with this anyone?

Answer (score 0):

you can access the formatter from the jump bar at the top of the window. if you select the component you added the formatter to, click and hold and it will turn into a drop down menu. move to the sub menu and the formatter should show up where you can select it.

it seems that you can treat the whole ui like a cascading set of menus that way.

now removing the formatter, that's a different question...
... which after further looking revealed:

over on the left side of the IB window in xcode4 is a 'dock' containing the icons for file owner, first responder etc. this column is expandable, and when you do so will show a hierarchical view of the nib file. through which you can navigate like the finder.

also, see this article:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH6-SW3

Comment: clicking and holding doesn't work in XCode 4.4.1. There doesn't seem to be any intuitive way to access the formatter after you add it.